# Ansätze to solve 2-dimensional nonlinear integral curve

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve the initial value problem analytically $X(t_0) = X_0, X \in \mathbb{R}^2$ for the following integral curve:

$x'(t) = -y(t)+x(t) (x(t)^2+y(t)^2-1) \\
y'(t) = x(t)+y(t) (x(t)^2+y(t)^2-1) $

According to the Picard–Lindelöf theorem there should be a solution for at least some period of time since the system is locally Lipschitz continuous. All differential equations I solved analytically so far were either one dimensional (seperation of variables, using $e^\lambda$) or linear (variation of parameters).

So far I figured out, that trajectories will converge towards the unit circle. But I still can not figure out a method how to calcluate an analytical solution.

Is there a known method to solve these systems? I would be gratefull just for the hint to a method I could use. Or is it completely hopeless to find a closed solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. We expand both equations by $y$ (first equation) and by $x$ (second equation).

$$x'y=-y^2+xy(x^2+y^2-1)$$
$$y'x=x^2+xy(x^2+y^2-1)$$

Now subtract both equations

$$y'x-x'y=x^2+y^2$$

After deviding by $x^2$, we obtain:

$$\frac{y'x-yx'}{x^2}=1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

Notice that we have the derivative of $y/x$ on the left side:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

Substitute $u(t)=\frac{y}{x}$ to get

$$\frac{d u}{dt}=1+u^2$$
This DE has $u(t)=\tan(t)$ as solution.

Now you can substitute $y(t)=x(t)\tan(t)$ into the second equation. Which will be in $x$ and $t$ only.

Comment: I can now calculate the solution for $z=\frac{y}{x}$ using seperation of variables. This gives me the equation $z = tan(constant + z)$. Which I find strange since the unit circle is a periodic orbit and should have periodically changing y/x. I can sadly not figure out how this helps to find an equation for x or y directly?

Comment: I edited my answer. After pluging $y(t)=x(t)\tan(t)$ into your second initial equation, try to see if the substituted form is easier to solve.

Comment: When I did my seperation of variables I did the misstake to write z instead of t. That way I could not find a solution. Now it worked. Using polar coordinates as Frits Veerman suggested seems to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

A big hint is that, if a solution $(x_c(t),y_c(t))$ lies on the unit circle, then you have $x_c(t)^2 + y_c(t)^2 = 1$. Assume that there exists a solution to your system which entirely lies on the unit circle, so assume that $(x_c(t),y_c(t))$ is a solution to your dynamical system. Then, as you can quickly see, for a solution on the unit circle, your system simplifies quite a lot. In particular, you can solve the resulting system for $x_c(t),y_c(t))$ quite easily, and obtain an explicit expression for the solution of your dynamical system on the unit circle.

Alternatively, you can try to write the system in *polar coordinates*. That is, you transform your cartesian coordinates $(x,y)$ to
\begin{align}
x(t) &= r(t) \cos \theta(t),\\
y(t) &= r(t) \sin \theta(t),
\end{align}
with $r(t) > 0$. This also gives more insight into the dynamics of the system for solutions which do not lie on the unit circle, if you're interested.

Comment: If it lies on the unit circle I obtain the solution $x = cos(t), y = sin(t) $ which is the periodic orbit. I did not think about polar coordinates before. I will use them and add the equations together so that I get an explicit formula for $r$ and $\Theta$.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that my answer helped! Feel free to accept it if it was useful to you.